# How to read text data in particular font using C#?

Tags: c#

Consider a notepad Text.txt which has a data that can be read only with font "Terminal". How to implement in C#? The content of notepad is readable only if i set the font to "Terminal". Otherwise i could see only Boxes. C# has to read the content using "Terminal" font so that it can get the exact data rather than a BOX. Tried with UTF8. Same response.

Even if i write the content of notepad here i could see hyphens.

EG:

The text is – but im not meaning hyphen. The actual word is double dot above n. It can be see only with Terminal font in notepad.

[image]

Comment: what do you want? Text data is indpependent of font. Rendering/Printing etc can display data into different fonts

Comment: Use the very same font in the application that displays the text.

Comment: The text is – but im not meaning hyphen. The actual word is double dot above n. It can be see only with Terminal font in notepad. Now i have to create an application in c# which can read that double dot above n and not a box. Hope i am clear.

Comment: @Naag_Algates then you should ask this question and not the one above. This one makes sense, but it shouldn't been hidden in the comments. Click the edit button below your question to do this.

Comment: How does your C# code look? Because you _have_ tried something that didn't work out? Right..? Show us what _didn't_ work, then people might be able to point out what's wrong.

Comment: You are describing a Latin letter N with a diaresis.  But as far as I know, there is no Unicode character for that combination.  Certainly there is no glyph in Windows Terminal for that combination.  There is a Latin letter N with a tilde, both small and capital N.  And there is a glyph for that in Terminal and in many other fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably the encoding (codepage) of the text file.
In what language is the text file written?
For example, if the file contained Greek text (codepage 1253), you would use something like this:

```
System.Text.Encoding GreekEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1253);
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt", GreekEncoding);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
```

Comment: Though i didnt get a perfect solution, your encoding idea gave a different thought to experiment. I get different figures in application's text box, when i copy and paste those figures in notepad i get the perfect result which i want. Without encoding the above technique(getting data from textbox and pasting in notepad) also failed. So thanks @svenv!

Comment: And below i have explained how i got rid of this.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually no `font` information saved in `.txt files`.

Simply use the same font in C# you expect to see in .txt file.

Comment: "Terminal" Font is not available in Visual Studio 2005!

Comment: let me know how to use a font for reading it. Can you give me example .what is the default font used in c# to read data.

Answer (score 1):

Text data is always independent of fonts,so i think there is no as such answer for your question

Comment: True! But application's text box doesn't show the content that i have show in question. It looks like comma, hyphen etc but not as original like double dot above A. Because "Terminal" font is not available in VS 2005!

Answer (score -1):

```
Encoding GreekEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sNotepadName+".txt", GreekEncoding))
{
    while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        sTempInput = input.Split('='); //Data - double dotted above A=A
        lMyDictionary.Add(sTempInput[0],sTempInput[1]);

    }
}
```

After adding into dictionary, if A is entered i have to display double dotted above A symbol in the textbox.

```
string[] sSplitedText = sEnteredText.Split(' '); //Because many letters can be entered with sapce as delimiter 
foreach(string sNewStr in sSplitedText)
{
    if (lMyDictionary.ContainsKey(sNewStr))
    {
        sReturnText += lMyDictionary[sNewStr];
    }
}
ResultDisplayTextBox.Text = sReturnText;
```

Since "Terminal" font is not available in vs2005 the result in textbox will be a box or comma or hyphen etc. If this data copied and pasted in notepad with "Terminal" font we could see the data. If encoding technique is not used, even though you paste the data from textbox it'll look like a heart or any other symbol. So my problem is sorted out. Thanks for all your replies.